# Replacing special values with average of the column

Tags: r, replace, missing-data

If i want to replace all the negative values as well as values of (999,9991,9992,9996) for all the columns of my data frame with the mean of that column, how should i do it. i tried the following but didnt work

```
x<-c(-1,-2,0,1,9991)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,999)
z<-c(100,101,-999,9992,9996)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

# replacing special values with missing first
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x){
x[x < 0 | x %in% c(999, 9991, 9992, 9996)] <- NA
return(x)
})

# and now replacing missing values with mean of column
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x){
x[is.na(x)]<- mean(x)
return(x)
})
```

but when i run this in R it doesnt replace the missing values

Comment: You need `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: it did work. thank you